# RactiveJS on-enter plugin missing

Tags: ractivejs

I've been looking for the "on-enter" plugin which seems to be working in the **Tutorials** section found [here](http://learn.ractivejs.org/partials/1). Wierd fact, in the plugins section the `keys events` plugin went missing ( or link didn't get updated, whatever ).

Problem is, there's nothing regarding that in the tutorial but it works there. So if anyone has a link or something, it'd be great !

I'm tired of on-keydown's :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of: https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive-events-keys.

via npm (`> npm i ractive-events-keys --save`):

```
var keys = require( 'ractive-events-keys' );
Ractive.events.enter = keys.enter;
```

Or just as browser script (available in the `dist` folder of the project):

```
<script src='ractive.js'></script>
<script src='ractive-events-keys.js'></script>
```

Comment: Hei Marty, I've added this file ( found it while searching the repository ) but it returns me an error. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =>`. From that `return ( node, fire ) => {`, I understand it is ES6, but I'm using the latest Chrome.. If it's the same as in the Tutorials section, how come it works there and it returns an error here...

Comment: I am using `ractive-events-keys.js` without problems in many projects.

Comment: I've updated the link on the demo page of the project to point to the correct version of the file